# Use dedicated GPU (Nvidia) and internal GPU (Intel) at the same time?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, Desktop.

I always had a Monitor on the dedicated GPU (Nvidia) and one monitor on the internal GPU (Intel). Last one I only use for some youtube tutorials.

However, I recently changed something in the Nvidia X Server Settings and created a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.

I restarted PC and the second monitor (plugged in the internal GPU) is not working anymore. If I plug it into the dedicated gpu it works fine.

I wonder, if theres something I can add to the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file to enable the internal gpu again so that I can use both?

Comment: There is a "bumblebee" project for Nvidia Optimus on laptops that'll allow the use of both cards - but it won't work on a PC.  I haven't heard of anything else that you could use on two different GPUs simultaneously.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498203/edit) your question and include the changes you made in "Nvidia X Server Settings" and `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`